# Install pandoc with no administrator access

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm am using `rmarkdown` to generate a word output and need `pandoc` to do so. Unfortunately I do not have administrator access on my work computer so I can't run the installer or use the `install.pandoc()` option.

I have tried downloading both the .zip and .tar.gz files from [the github site](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.2.1) and tried to install them manually using the "install" tab in RStudio, but get the error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'pandoc-2.2.1-windows-x86/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

[Here](https://pandoc.org/installing.html) states "If you prefer not to use the msi installer, we also provide a zip file that contains pandoc’s binaries and documentation. Simply unzip this file and move the binaries to a directory of your choice."

maybe I don't know what they mean by "move the binaries to a directory of your choice." - When I unzip the files, I still cannot access the package.

Side note - I have defined `.libpaths()` to allow me to install other packages, but i cannot get pandoc to work.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc is a terminal application and does not require R-Studio to install it unziping the .tar.gz file with

linux: tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz

for windows the binary is the program pandoc itself that is unzipped from the zip file
simply unzip the file and pandoc should already be installed in the unzipped folder

after unzipping you might want to move pandoc.exe (for windows) int the directory where the project is located so that it is recognized

Comment: The file I am unzipping is "pandoc-2.2.1" which is not recognized when I look for the package list. When I type `library(pandoc)` is says "Error in library(pandoc) : there is no package called ‘pandoc’ ". Moving the .exe file into the file with the libraries has no effect. I am using windows 7. I must be putting the file somewhere incorrectly, but I'm not sure which file I should be putting in which directory.... Ideas?

Comment: Ahh - sorry I got it. Moving the .exe file that was unzipped into the *project* folder, not the *library* folder got it. Thanks!

Comment: To follow up - moving the .exe file actually didn't solve the problem when I tried it on my work computer. You still need administrator access.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two steps in this process for me to get it to work.

1: Install Pandoc

First download the MSI from https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/

If you have trouble installing the MSI by right clicking on it, try creating a batch file with the contents:

```
cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" %1"
```

Then drag and drop the MSI on to this batch file and it will install without asking for any admin privileges.

2:
You'll need to tell the script to find Pandoc if its not running in RStudio already:

```
if(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") != "1"){rmarkdown::find_pandoc(dir = Sys.getenv("pandoc_path"))}
```

For me `Sys.getenv("pandoc_path")` = `C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Pandoc`